# PrismaCloud CVE-2022-36437

Tags: java, hazelcast, payara-micro, cve

Prisma Cloud reports Vulnerability in hazelcast CVE-2022-36437
The thing is that the project **does not** use hazelcast. It uses payara-micro 6.2023.1

What is the connection between hazlecast and payara-micro?

How to solve this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payara micro is using Hazelcast for clustering or some "core" features  . E.g. remote CDI events passed through Hazelcast. As far as I know this vulnerability fixed in 5.1.3 but Payara Micro using 5.1.1. Probably it works if you override Hazelcast dependency in your project descriptor (e.g. pom.xml)